# How do I read a text file containing an array and place it in an array? (Python)

Tags: python

```
from numpy import *

f = open('matrix.txt', 'r')

x = []
for line in f.readlines():
    y = [value for value in line.split()]
    x.append(y)

f.close()

x = map(int, x)

a = array([x])
```

Basically, my code is suppose to open the text file and put it into the list x. I then change those values in x into an integer and place that in an array a. Is there a faster way to do this? Btw my code doesn't work.

Comment: What is in the file? Does it contain multiple lines?

Comment: Yeah just multiple lines with numbers spaced out, only numbers, no other characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
with open('matrix.txt', 'r') as f:
    x = []
    for line in f:
        x.append(map(int, line.split()))
print x
print np.array(x)
```

With matrix.txt containing 3 lines with 4 numbers each:

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 8 7 6
```

as above, this prints

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 8, 7, 6]]
[[1 2 3 4]
 [5 6 7 8]
 [9 8 7 6]]
```

However, as mentioned in a previous answer, consider using  [numpy.loadtxt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html).  For example, if
`print np.loadtxt('matrix.txt')`
is added to the program, it also prints out

```
[[ 1.  2.  3.  4.]
 [ 5.  6.  7.  8.]
 [ 9.  8.  7.  6.]]
```

Comment: does that just automatically convert it into an array?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you could even specify `dtype` when you pass it to `np.loadtxt` to retrieve integers as it appears that is what OP wants.

Comment: @mgilson, yes, either of the following produces the matrix with integers: `print np.loadtxt('matrix.txt', int)` or `print np.loadtxt('matrix.txt', dtype=int)` (after saying `import numpy as np`)

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably do a little better if you use [`np.loadtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html).

Answer (score 0):

almost there...

the following lines create a list of list which you don't want

```
y = [value for value in line.split()]
x.append(y)
```

because of this the map call would fail

instead of these 2 lines use

```
x = [int(value) for value in line.split()]
```